# Clicking on a particular improvement request gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Title says it all really, but clicking on an improvement request gives a 404 page. The request I clicked on is in the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23) tag and is called [Extensions Add method for collection initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/24/4398). See the [full list of improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23?tab=needsimprovement) and the item is still there at the bottom of the list.

[image]

Comment: I get the same issue on the exact same link, 5 days later.

Comment: @ken2k Yeah, but I'm sure they've got bigger fish to fry right now with all the changes going on. I'm quite patient :)

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure they have other priorities for now... :) Still worth noting the bug is still present.

Comment: 3.5 weeks now and still seeing this 404, must be some kind of record now :)

Comment: @ken2k Do you think this will ever get fixed? :)

Comment: Well after 6 to 8 weeks maybe it'll be fixed ;)

Comment: I’m guessing that it’s a deleted example/topic, and the request wasn’t deleted automatically.

Comment: @JF Well it could be a hundred different reasons, I didn't want to speculate about the internals of the system.

Comment: I was just noticing that the topic/example doesn’t seem to exist under its then-current name anymore.

Comment: @ken2k I keep coming back to this to amuse myself. 4 months later and it's still there!

Comment: Yeah ;) I'm even starting to wonder if this whole "documentation" thing is still actively developed!