# Documentation Update, November 29th

Tags: discussion, documentation

Well, November 2016 sure was a month that happened.

Now that we're on the other side of the US election and holidays (and the team is back at work) it's time for an update on [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

[View the previous update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336627/documentation-update-october-20th).

### Shipped

#### Topic Introductions

Every topic now has an optional section above examples, an **Introduction**.

[image: Introduction in the editor]

Introductions should give readers an idea of what they're going to find on a topic, and help future contributors tell what belongs.

#### Improvement Requests

Improvement request have been updated.

[image: Improvement request flow]

For each type of a request, only a single one can be active on any given example or topic.  Improvement requests can now be commented on.  The entire improvement request element can also be collapsed, to save vertical space.

#### Introduction Topics Standardized

Introduction Topics (also known as Hello World topics, Root topics, Overview topics, etc.) now have a standardized title and display.

[image: Intro topic style]

The title is based off the friendly name of a tag, which can be edited by highrep users (anyone who has the [trusted privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) on a tag's wiki.

### Planned

#### Discussion

Another round of user testing has wrapped up on the (oft discussed) Discussion feature.  Thank you to those who participated, we've got a final design now.

Here's an updated mockup.

[image: Discussion mockup]

Proper implementation will start this week.  It's a complicated feature, but it'll make a good present for the holidays.

#### Topic/Example Menu De-Iconizing

We're going to be converting the menus in Documentation to display more like the menus on Q&A.

Basically

[image: New menus]

We'll also be moving these menus to a more familiar position.

#### Moving Topics

We're going to be adding an option in the coming weeks to move whole topics to different tags as part of a change.  This option will live in the "move examples"-popup currently at the top of a topic.

Comment: I'm a bit confused… 20 upvotes AND an SE staff member saying it was on the to-do list [here](/a/336975)… and it's not even listed as _planned_ here?

Comment: Why is there a 500 character length limit on introductions? In [JS Unary Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2084/), I (ab)used an pinned example as "Introduction", but just the markdown for the links in there is already 700 characters. The pinned example is an easy-to-browse index that really should be in the introduction.

Comment: ^ Even that comment is already 300 characters (Not counting the link).

Comment: @Cerbrus that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: @StephenLeppik: I've got multiple documentation bug reports [open](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus?tab=questions). I'd rather directly comment on a recent change, than having another report fade into nothing.

Comment: Nice and all, but I would seriously love to see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334371/indicate-that-a-proposed-change-has-reject-votes) implemented. It would be incredibly helpful for this to work like suggested edits and for _at least_ reject votes to be shown while the change is still pending. At least getting _some_ dev feedback on if that idea's likely to ever happen would be great...

Comment: I would love it if [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329111/clicking-on-a-particular-improvement-request-gives-a-404) issue I reported 4 months ago was fixed. It kinda blows my mind that it's still there...

Comment: @StephenLeppik According to an edit on that post 5 hours after you posted this, it has now been implemented.

Comment: @SGR I know. I get notified when someone edits my post.

Comment: @Cerbrus I promise we're looking at all Documentation bug reports even if there's no immediate response. For us to remember that the issue exists and to track community support (through votes, answers, etc), a separate question beats a comment on a temporally-relevant feature announcement any day.

Comment: @Cerbrus If I recall, the reasoning for the length limit was to prevent the intro section from growing too large to really be called an intro. We did, however, pick a number sort of out of a hat, so some adjustment is possible if there's a need. [status-beta] and all. (Or we could build something else that addresses said need.) Not to harp on the same point, but this is also where a separate question shines since examples of whatever needs aren't being served can be gathered, discussed, etc.

Comment: @AdamLear: Thanks for the reply. I've submitted a [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338851/increase-the-character-limit-for-documentation-introductions) to increase the limit. (Figured it's not really a "bug")

Comment: *"request improvement"* as a two-word link just doesn't feel right. *"flag"* would be inappropriate here. I know there's already *"improve this question"* for anonymous users on the main site, but there are fewer other links there. Maybe someone could think of a one-word link that fits well there.

Comment: I like the idea of SF Documentation. But I must say I'm a bit underwhelmed with how it is evolving. I've contributed a couple of times mainly to get a feel for it. No edits, upvotes or anything. My impression with most topics I've looked at is that there is indeed not a lot happening and the little that is happening is of little interest to anyone. I think the whole approval/review bureaucracy is just holding things back currently. I'd suggest removing the feature completely and simply rely on up votes/down votes for quality based filtering. There's too much friction currently.

Comment: when will the Comments be online?

Comment: WRT @Cerbrus idea, I have to disagree. People are capable of scrolling down to see the other examples, the introduction does not need to be an index (note they are even called different things "introduction" vs "index"!). An introduction should be just that, a short piece that presents the topic in question to the casual reader that requires more than a quick reference lookup.